# how to get a word matching almost like a word in column in sql using query builder

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, search

i have a searchbox in my website build using codeigniter, I have used the query builder in modal to get the data which user enters in the searchbox, the query is like below:

```html
public function fetchsearch($limit, $start, $query) {
        
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->join('link','link.category=category.category_name');
        if($query != "")
        {
            $this->db->like('link.link_name',$query,'both');
            $this->db->or_like('category.category_name',$query,'both');
            $this->db->or_like('link.keyword',$query,'both');
        }
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get('category');
        // $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

the problem here is, when the query searches the exact word, if there is no match then no result is displayed, where as I want the query to search for, say user entered "musec", the query should match "music". means the query should just look for an approx match in the word.

can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this, thanks in advance.

Comment: search `levenshtein distance in MySQL` there are a lot of questions on SO and beyond

Comment: @leftjoin i searched as you said, but didn't understand anything, as I am new to coding. can u please show as an answer if possible

Comment: Unfortunately, indexing for matching using levenshtein distance is complex topic and I know no databases which support it out of the box. Study what others did and maybe you will invent the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution/code that I used in my all code codeigniter based projects:

```
      public function get_search_count($q)
      {
        $qarray = explode(' ', $q);

        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->like('product_name', $q, 'both');
        if (count($qarray) > 1) {
          foreach ($qarray as $s) {
            $this->db->or_like('product_seo_title', $s, 'both');
            $this->db->or_like('product_seo_description', $s, 'both');
            $this->db->or_like('product_seo_keyword', $s, 'both');
          }
        } else {
          $this->db->or_like('product_seo_title', $q, 'both');
          $this->db->or_like('product_seo_description', $q, 'both');
          $this->db->or_like('product_seo_keyword', $q, 'both');
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->results();
      }
```

Comment: hi, can you please tell me what does this function do?

Comment: User can search product word by word and get combined result of products.

Comment: This answer should be [edit]ed to include an educational explanation.  Remember, your answer is here to not only help the OP, but thousands of future researchers.